# The accuracy is 0 for my model using tensorflow, what do I do wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

First of all, I just want to clarify that I'm a beginner with AI and I've never used TensorFlow.

So basically I want to make an AI that can predict the Critic_Score based on 13 features and this is the way I implemented it:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(13,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss= tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc')]
)
batch_size = 32
epochs = 30
history = model.fit(
     X_train,
     y_train,
     validation_split=0.2,
     batch_size = batch_size,
     epochs = epochs,
     callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau()],
     verbose=0,

)

deepLearningEv = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)


prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

[Img predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSFlm.png)

And all my predictions are 1, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you specify, what kind of output you expect your model to create (e.g. share one sample from Y_train)? The sigmoid function you use for the output layer can be seen as kind of a probability of a value to be either 0 or 1.

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies almost certainly in your output function.
The sigmoid function you use can create values between 0 and 1 which is

I would advise you to take a look at the following resources.
"Sigmoid — This results in a value between 0 and 1 which we can infer to be how confident the model is of the example being in the class", taken from *[here](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-which-loss-and-activation-functions-should-i-use-ac02f1c56aa8)*

So in your case, only predictions of 1 could mean, that the model wants to predict higher values but can't. Also, the very high MEA hints at that being the case as well.